# How can I deploy a smart device application to a reconfigured WinMo emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework, emulation

I've reconfigured the default Windows Mobile 6 Professional emulator to increase it's memory size and now I would like to deploy and debug my CF application on it.

The problem is that it is not possible to select this newly created emulator configuration from the Target Device drop-down in VS2008. If I select Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator, it simply starts the default emulator.

Is it possible to run the application on a custom emulator configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a `.decfg` config file for your custom emulator? Make sure you store it in your `[User]\My Documents\My Device Emulators` folder.

If you then have a look in the Device Emulator Manager (in the Tools menu) in VS2008 it should show up under My Device Emulators. And it should also appear in the dropdown on the Device toolbar, where you can select it to start debugging on it.

Comment: No go, unfortunately. I have the .decfg in My Device Emulators, it's displayed in the Device Emulator Manager as you say, but still doesn't show up in the Device drop down. I've obviously restarted VS since creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way to do this.  If you are after the memory increase, next to the above mentioned device drop down on the Visual Studio toolbar there is a button with the tooltip 'Device Options'.  Click this button.  You can then select the desired  Windows Mobile 6 emulator image (eg, Pro..) and click Save As. Give it a new name like 'My Uber Emulator' and after saving click the properties.  There is an emulator options button on the properties page. This opens up the properties page that normally has the RAM option disabled, however you can here specify it and save it.

Once you have made these changes, this new emulator will be available for deployment because it is Visual Studio endorsed.  This has just solved my problem.

Any questions, please as.

Hope this helps,
Steve